# Changing the data of a f.label after the user presses f.submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

So I currently have this code in the html.erb:

> <%= f.label :user_id %>
>       <%= f.field :user_id %>

I want the user to enter an email into the field in which it converts it into user_id using this:

> User.find_by_email("xyz@abc.com").id

However, I have no idea how to use it or know whether this will even work. Will appreciate some help on this as I am quite new to rails. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to get the value of the user's email after they press the submit button?

**Update**
Try this:

```
User.find_by(email: params[:user_id])
```

This will work after the user presses the submit button, but you have to assign it to a variable if you want to use it somewhere else.

Comment: I am trying to get the user_id based on the unique email that they will enter into the field after they press the submit button.

Comment: Do you have a ```user_id``` field in your database?

Comment: I do have a user_id field

Comment: Are you trying to store the email address in the user_id field?

Comment: No, I am trying to get the user_id via the email address that the user will input into the field, hence:

User.find_by_email("xyz@abc.com").id